# VueJS Typescript - DOM not updating with variable in Super Class

Tags: typescript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

Essentially I have a BaseAuthController with on common login functions and variables, I then have a SignupController and a LoginController that inherit from the BaseAuthController. I have looked at the variable through breakpoints and the variables are all being set correctly and they exist. The issue is changing the variable in the super class is not then updating the DOM

BaseAuthController.ts

```
import { RouterStates } from './../../../routing/RouterStates';
import Vue from "vue";

export class BaseAuthController extends Vue
{
// Variables
// ==================================================================

protected errorMessage: string = '';

// Login handling
// ==================================================================

/**
 * Handle loging in
 * @param {firebase.auth.UserCredential} respone 
 */
protected onLoginSuccess(respone: firebase.auth.UserCredential): void
{
    if (respone.user)
    {
        let user: firebase.User = respone.user;
        if (user.emailVerified)
        {
            this.$router.replace(RouterStates.APP);
        }
        else
        {
            user.sendEmailVerification()
                .then(() => 
                {
                    this.$router.replace(RouterStates.VERIFY_EMAIL);
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    }
}
}
```

SignupController.vue

```
<template>
<div class="signup-controller__row">
    <div class="h-group v-align-center">
        <div class="signup-controller__error-image tight"></div>
        <div class="signup-controller__error-message">{{ errorMessage }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script src="./SignupController.ts"></script>
```

SignupController.ts

```
export default class SignupController extends BaseAuthController {

// Variables
// ===============================================================

private confirmPassword: string = '';
private creationDetails: AccountCreationDetails = 
{
    email: '',
    password: ''
}

/**
 * Create an account
 * @returns void
 */
private onCreateAccountClick(): void
{

    if (this.creationDetails && this.creationDetails.email != '')
    {
        if (this.creationDetails && this.creationDetails.password != '')
        {
            if (this.confirmPassword != '')
            {
                if (StringUtil.validateEmail(this.creationDetails.email))
                {
                    if (this.creationDetails.password == this.confirmPassword)
                    {
                        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.creationDetails.email, this.creationDetails.password)
                            .then((respone: firebase.auth.UserCredential) => this.onLoginSuccess(respone))
                            .catch(() => 
                            {
                                this.errorMessage = 'There was an issue creating your account';
                            });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.errorMessage = 'Passwords do not match';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.errorMessage = 'Please enter a valid email address';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.errorMessage = 'Please confirm your password';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.errorMessage = 'Please enter a password';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.errorMessage = 'Please enter your email address';
        console.log(this.errorMessage);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting the `data` for the Vue instance, which is bound to the DOM initially but does not get updated nor are changes tracked to this `data` variable. You need to create a `computed` data property via a setter on your TypeScript class, like this:

```
get computedErrorMessage() {
    return this.errorMessage;
}
```

Now in your `SignupController.vue` file, reference the `computedErrorMessage` property instead of the `errorMessage` variable, like this:

```
<div class="signup-controller__error-message">{{ computedErrorMessage }}</div>
```

The `computed` property monitors any `data` variables that are part of its logic, in your case just `this.errorMessage`; so whenever `this.errorMessage` changes then the `computedErrorMessage` is updated and Vue is notified and that value is pushed down to the DOM.

Comment: Just to confirm, I have added get computedErrorMessage() { return this.errorMessage; } in my SignupController.ts file and updated my SignupController.vue file with <div class="signup-controller__error-message">{{ computedErrorMessage }}</div>

However, it is still not working? You are correct in that it grabs the initial value, but from then on it doesn't update with the getter? I can only get it to work if I call this.$forceupdate() which I know is super gross.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this not working in something like jsFiddle? Having full code to work and tweak will help you get to a solution faster.