# Vue.js Typescript component does not update view on async callbacks

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, callback, xmlhttprequest

Been scratching my head for hours around this:

`simpleValue` never gets updated and always print "hello".

(Even tried the getter as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682340)

```js
<template>
    <div id="app">
        {{ simpleValue }}
        {{ getSimpleValue() }}
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component({
        components: {}
    })

    export default class App extends Vue {
        private simpleValue = 'hello';

        getSimpleValue = () => {
            return this.simpleValue;
        }

        constructor() {
            super();

            setTimeout(() => {
                this.simpleValue = 'goodbye';
            }, 150);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: what happens if you change `constructor()` to `created()` or `mounted()`?

Comment: Wow.. It works! Thanks a bunch!

I thought `constructor()` was the TS equivalent of a 'mounted' lifecycle event..

Comment: nope, I haven't seen `constructor()` referenced anywhere

Comment: I guess I got it from there: https://johnpapa.net/vue-typescript/#appvue